# How to organize my data to create a heatmap using correlation or cluster analysis (x must be numeric problem)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering, pearson-correlation

I need some help with generating heatmaps with cluster analysis and correlation (I am new to R). My data looks like this in Excel:

```
               Gene1   Gene2   Gene3   Gene4   Gene5  ...  Gene296

   Bacteria1     0       0       0      0.7     0.2   ...     0

   Bacteria2    0.44     0       0       0       0    ...    0.9 

   Bacteria2     0      0.32     0      0.4      0    ...     0

     ...        ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   ...    ...

   Bacteria117   0      0.2     0.3      0      0.7   ...     0
```

A value of 0.32 represents a score of 32 from 0 to 100. There are higher scores (0.9 for example) or lower scores (0 or 0.2 for example). I checked for NAs and there are none. I want to do cluster analysis to find out what bacteria form clusters according to my experimental data (scores). The file is CSV. I used this code:

```
> aa <- read.csv(file.choose())
> str(aa)

#I obtain this structure

'data.frame':   117 obs. of  296 variables:
 $ X                        : Factor w/ 117 levels "Ac_neuii_BVI",..: 45 64 67 104 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
 $ AAC6_Iad                 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ aad6                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ abeS                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

> is.numeric(aa)
[1] FALSE
```

When I try to use the correlation or the clustering I get this error:

```
> az <- cor(aa)
Error in cor(aa) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I tried as.matrix but the error continues in the matrix of course. I tried as.numeric but it didn't work. I erased X `> aa$X <- NULL` and the problem disappeared (I don't know if this is the correct way to solve the problem), but the name of the bacteria disapeared and then I get a correlation between my genes, not between my genes AND the bacteria. The same thing happens with the clustering using hclust or dist. Is there a way I should organize my csv file? I haven't found a clear article on the internet on how to solve the "x must be numeric problem" and on how to do the correlation or measuring the distances between the genes and the bacteria.

Thank you. Sorry for the ignorance on certain things that might appear obvious to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the bacteria names as row.names:

```
aa <- read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`aa$X` is not numeric (it contains factors). You can transform it with:

```
aa$X = as.numeric(aa$X)
```

Then `az <- cor(aa)` will run... but (as noted by @Cole) it does not make sense since `X` refers to the names of the bacteria.

You can set the first column to be the names of the rows with the `row.names` parameter of `read.csv`:

```
aa <- read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1)
```

Comment: The edit you made is similar to the other answer by @Cole.